# What is the difference between Microservices and Monolythical approach for the provided use-case

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

So I started reading some things about different software architectures and inevitably came across Microservices Architecture. Yet, I am wondering about the way these achitectures differ from each other. In a monolythical approach I would e.g. modify a `POM.XML` to take my different layers and pack them into one application to deploy it. I'd say this might even be the most common way to set up a simple application.

Now as I understood Microservices, you seperate each service from each other and let them run independently. For me that means, that every service is deployed on its own (so you basically got a `tomcat` running with quite a lot of `.war`-files on it. But I think I miss the difference to a monolythical application.

I am going to try to set an (quite common) example:

You got a frontend (e.g. `Angular`) with a `Spring-Boot` Backend communicating via `REST`-Services. Now I take a `POM.XML` and do the following steps:

- build the Frontend-Application
- include the necessary JS-files into my Spring-Application
- create `WAR`-file from the project

As a result I got one single `WAR`-file that I can deploy but got two Services included: Backend and Frontend. Yet, I would call it a monolythical approach.

Now when I would include the `Angular`-Application into my tomcat and deploy a `WAR`-file of my `Spring-Boot` part of the application (without integrated frontend). That way I would have two deployed services running on the same server interacting with each other that can be replaced without touching each other. By definition I would not call it a monolythical approach (same code, different deployment) but a Microservice-architecture, right? But this can not be the case since literally every article I read told me the same advantages and disadvantages for architectures and I cannot see any difference except for the possibility to exchange frontend and backend (which I have in both cases, yet in one I would need to redeploy the full application in the first case).

Comment: The difference is not so much about the modularity in the code as it is about the granularity of runtime components. So you could still build microservices from the same codebase and deploy different components (in my opinion, you could even build all microservices as the same artifact, but call the binaries differently at runtime).

Comment: "you basically got a tomcat running with quite a lot of .war-files on it.". With microservices, you would be able (once that makes sense scale-wise) to instead of that have many tomcats running on many servers with one war file each. Or to replace one of these services with a different implemention (could be very different, different language or even externally provided Saas). With a monolith, it is not possible to pull out individual pieces easily.

Comment: "two Services included: Backend and Frontend."  With microservices, you would have many parts that collectively make up the backend. (I'd argue that you can still deploy them together, but conceptually they are independent pieces).

Comment: @Thilo Let me catch up the last thing you said about the backend: That means e.g. I got 20 different API's that I call to get data from (e.g. for Books, Cars, Users and so on). In a MS-approach I'd have one independent part for each API so that I can replace my "Books"-Module by another "Books"-Module. But when I would build it monolythical, I'd still use different Models for each API that I can request that are independent from each other to keep modularity, right?

Comment: @ernest_k So for me to clarifiy your argument: You mean that I provide the service X (lets just say my backend functionality) from version 0.4 but I use the frontend from my version 1.4 in the same deploy? But for me that is also something you could do in a monolythical approach, that's my problem. I think I am missing a small piece of information that keeps me from enlightment-

Comment: @Rüdiger for a real example of both monolithic and microservices you can visit this project: https://www.jhipster.tech/. Try to make both types of applications and lunch them.

Comment: @Spara That was part of the confusion tbh. When I use the monolythical approach of JHipster I get one big project where everything is included and when I use the microservice I just get one small service. Yet I am wondering why one big project that is build strictly modular (where I can use any version of any module as long as the API allows it) would differ from a microservice-architecture, since I cannot see that there would be any more advantages or disadvantages except for the number of servers I can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microservices are set just set of guide lines that talk about how to design your application so that it is scalable, manageable and adapts to fast development pace. It is not just about how you are deploying your application.

Over the years, we have learned that when you try build one big application as monolith, initially it gives you pace, different modules in your monolith has complete visibility of each other and can access things, tweak things around as they wish, even one change that should affect one module may migrate into other classes, where it should not have been. While it helps you prototype, but code becomes less and less maintainable. You can ofcourse put in effort to make sure your code remains clean, but that effort grows as app grows.

Also you as developer are required to know whole product and it is difficult to work in silo, without worrying about the whole architecture, which makes it difficult for new people to join and make changes.

Next when you deploy, specially now a day, scale is important, and you need to adapt to traffic. All your modules will not expect high traffic 24/7. But if you have monolith, even if one module is being used by 100 of users your application have to scale for 100 of users.

Microservices just pulls in info from this, and defines some guidelines

1. You should breakdown your app based on biz domains. Every service is responsible for one aspect only. They talk to other via contract (API or events) and as long as contract stands you can do what you want within your service. New dev need to learn just one service to start with.
2. Scaling becomes easy, because if you have load on one service only that will scale. Other modules deployed independently can scale as the load specific to them.
3. By keeping it small you can build fast, make changes in rapid way. No shared database make sure that you take a call on what you want to save, how you want to save and how you want to change.

For you case, just deploy it the way you think its best. But if you start to grow, you have some 50 odd services (or that size project) you will see benefits of divide and conquer.

Comment: So these architectures are most likely based on the modularity of my code and not whether I got one, two or twenty different services running? E.g. you would not call it a monolyth when I got 5 modules that can run independently from each other (but might share the same database) and just communicate to the frontend and the database-server? Although it is deployed in one large WAR-file?

Comment: it is not about what you call them. Microservices are guidelines, if you breach one you may end up in trouble, for instance if they share database, user database, it may seem fine initially as order can get user data directly, but then you are storing say hash of password as well and its visiible to every one now, what if order service updated that, or added a new column to user data. Now you user service need to go and figure out why it was added, what is the impact, what are the validations etc. It will make life lil difficult. tomorrow, and so services should be independent, no sharing.

Comment: Okay, this seems to be a good approach, thanks for that clarification! You also got a point on the database there, so it might even be more useful to make one "larger" service instead of two that share the same database I guess.

Comment: Yes, but what decides the boundaries of the service is basically your understanding of the domains and how they interact with each other. it is bit difficult . You may start with larger service, if it works well, good else you split it down, or vise versa. Microserivces allow you to evolve rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Spliting Frontend from Backend is not the best/canonical example of microservices deployments; this is the equivalent of having layers in a monolith. Thing better about how you'd split your monolith by (sub)domain into modules, each module having frontend and backend responsibilities; then each module can become a microservice, if needed.

The canonical MS architecture for a web-based app is a Gateway that assembles (in paralel!) HTML responses from different MSs. So, individual MS would respond with HTML, CSS and JS instead of JSON or other incomplete form of data. This is [Tell Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle applied to MSs. This gives you a real MS, in which you can very easily replace one MS with another.

If the Gateway cannot assemble the individual responses in parallel because they depend one another then the splitting is wrong and you need to refactor.

The biggest notable difference between a modular monolith and microservices is that microservices run in separate processes.

If you create your monolith using location [transparency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(human%E2%80%93computer_interaction)), then you could deploy components as microservices without touching others' components code. For example if you use CQRS, you could deploy a Readmodel as a microservice just by using cut/paste on your code, from monolith to microservice.